# os.setuid doesn't change current user

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I wanted to change current user for script execution. I did this

```
import os
newuid = pwd.getpwnam('newuser').pw_uid
os.setuid(newuid)    
print('User :' + getpass.getuser());
```

I am still getting `root`. Is there better way than this? I want switch user once and then continue rest of the commands execution in the script with that new user.

Answer (score 5):

`getpass.getuser()` doesn't use `getuid()` or `geteuid()` to get the current user.

http://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getuser

> This function checks the environment variables LOGNAME, USER, LNAME and USERNAME, in order, and returns the value of the first one which is set to a non-empty string. If none are set, the login name from the password database is returned on systems which support the pwd module, otherwise, an exception is raised.

Comment: ok. But still it(setuid) doesn't change the user at all. I am still getting the execution output as root.

Comment: I ran manually with root and outputs for manual and script match. The scripts need to be run with that user. It is failing.

Comment: seteuid() changes the effective user id, not the real uid. You have to drop the real uid with os.setuid().

Comment: @Tiran How to drop that?

Comment: @Tiran that's what I am using `setuid()`. Not getting you, can you clear more on this.

Comment: Neither setuid nor seteuid affect the output of getpass.getuser(). getuser() doesn't account for the owner of the process. It just uses an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

After trying modules `os`, `subprocess`, `getpass`, I realised that the problem is not whether the user is set. The user gets set or gets changed using `os.setuid`, however, the methods from modules to get username like `os.getlogin()`, `getpass.getuser()`, actually does not get username properly. If you run a shell command `whoami` or `id`using `subprocess.Popen()` or `os.system()`, you will get the changed user. These are little puzzled outputs for me. Below is script which shows all these weird behaviours.

```
import os
import subprocess
import pwd
import getpass

#os.chdir("/tmp")

#uid = pwd.getpwnam('newuser').pw_uid

os.setuid(500)     # newuser's id found from shell cmd line

print os.getuid()

p = subprocess.Popen(['id'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = p.communicate()

# print os.system('useradd newuser1') # Try this commenting, it will not create, and then  try commenting above line of setuid. i.e. it will become root, and then see the change.

# print os.getcwd()

print out,err

p = subprocess.Popen(['whoami'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = p.communicate()

print out,err

print getpass.getuser()

print os.getlogin()

print os.system('whoami')
```